# Assign a ContentControl resource to an inherited ContentControl element

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a trouble and i need your help. Here's my code:

```
public class CircleElement : ContentControl
{

public ContentControl me;
private FrameworkElement _parent;

public CircleElement()
{
  if (_parent != null)
  {
    me = (ContentControl)_parent.FindResource("CircleRes");
    me.Style = (Style)_parent.FindResource("CircleStyle");
  }

}
```

The CircleElement inherits the ContentControl and I would like to assign the resource "CircleRes" and the style "CircleStyle" to it. Something like:

```
this = (ContentControl)_parent.FindResource("CircleRes");
this.Style = (Style)_parent.FindResource("CircleStyle");
```

This thing is not allowable.So to get around this problem I instantiated the ContentControl me element; but the code is a little messy!! How to get it more "elegant" ???

Thanks in advance

Paolo

Comment: Why you are doing that? Can you explain? "I have two views (say, renders boundaries of some kind), one bla-bla..., and one view which is about to render inside both views...", for example. I just do not understand why you a trying to do such a thing programmatically rather than declaratively?

Comment: because I need to create as many circles into a canvas as the user click on a button "create circles".I solved the issue changing the resource tag from <ContentControl ... > to <r:CircleElements ... > and then calling into the constructor : this.Content = _parent.FindResource("CircleRes"); this.Style = (Style)_parent.FindResource("CircleStyle");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is a little strange but it is achievable in multiple ways...

Instead of having another content control (i.e. `me`) why not set `this` control's Content itself?

```
    this.Content
           = (ContentControl)_parent.FindResource("CircleRes"); 
    ((ContentControl)(this.Content)).Style
           = (Style)_parent.FindResource("CircleStyle"); //*** Potential problem
```

**Problem**: The Potential problem statement is marked this way because your code (and mine too) sets the style `"CircleStyle"` to `"CircleRes"` resource by reference.

How? `me` or `((ContentControl)(this.Content))` is nothing but `"CircleRes"` resource!

This means if `"CircleRes"` is referred in some other place, it will carry the `"CircleStyle"` as its own style along with it. And if you set some new `Style` to `"CircleRes"` somewhere else then it will **overwrite** the `Style` of `"CircleRes"` wherever is used, including the above code (where intended style is `"CircleStyle"`)

**Solution**: Use `ContentTemplate` instead. Templates don't cause a visual's by instance reference.

So actually you should have a DataTemplate (say "CircleResTemplate") and set that as ContentTemplate to `CircleElement` class.

```
   this.ContentTemplate
       = (DataTemplate)_parent.FindResource("CircleResTemplate");
   this.Style
       = (Style)_parent.FindResource("CircleStyle");
```

Let me know if this answers your question.